# Angular 2 + Bootstrap 4 - How do I fit the table height into a row?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am developing a meal planner application that allows user to get recipe/place order.
In one of the rows of the application, I show 3 tabs as given below.

[meal_planner_layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF3p3.png)

Code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-ycgcru?file=src/app/app.component.html

Order info is provided by the user. Delivery charge and tax are retrieved from the backend - simulated using setTimeout.

**Key requirement:** The row must take up 40% of viewing height. This is set using custom css class - row-fixed-height.
The table has a maximum of 1 header + 5 rows. The full table must fit into the row.

**Where it breaks:**
The nav tabs are not displaying correctly - This works on my system though.

The table exceeds the row height. So the buttons in the next row overlap the contents of the table. I tried setting h-100 but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be related to the HTML structure of a table. The perfect one is ... >tbody > tr > td, but yours is > tbody > **div > app-tax** > tr > td. These may make your table be rendered in weird ways.

I believe you can, at least, get rid of the extra div element by moving *ngFor on the app-tax host element.

You can hardcode the plain table structure to see if removing those fixes the table's behavior.

Comment: This fixed my bug. I made my table hierarchy clearer - table > tbody > tr > td.